# ViewData is not displaying information passed through URL MVC 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, viewdata

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 [free one on my Win 7] and just started evaluating its cool features.
Trying to use view data like this:

```
public class VandVController : Controller
{
    // GET: VandV
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult DisplayName(string name)
    {
        ViewData["name"] = name;
        return View();
    }
}
```

My View page looks like this:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "DisplayName";
}

 <h2>Welcome to MVC training Mr. @ViewData["name"]</h2>
```

From my URL, when I'm using like this:

```
 http://localhost:54748/VandV/DisplayName/abc
```

its displaying me: Welcome to MVC training Mr.
where as it should display : Welcome to MVC training Mr. abc.

Here is my route:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Could any one please tell me whats going wrong? How can I display correct sting? Thanks.

Comment: Please show your routes, maybe `name` is not populated

Comment: Do you have a specific route with `.../{name}`?

Comment: Thanks a Lot. Nice catch. changed my routes from id to name.

Answer (score 1):

Modified like below and working.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another route path to your configuration (change the route path name) and change the parameter name example as below

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Test", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{name}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Use new

```
 {controller="VandV" ,action="DisplayName",id = UrlParameter.Optional}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the issue? It because the parameter needs to be `{name}` not `{id}`!